# how to remove random numbers generated if they are less than a certain value

Tags: r

I'm generating random variates with `rnorm()` and need to remove any random variates that are less than 20.

for example:

```
rnorm(4, mean=30, sd=18)
[1] 18 25 36 16
```

needs to become:

```
[1] 25 36
```

Comment: Sounds like a 'truncated normal distribution' - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can subset the output `vector`

```
v2 <- v1[v1 >= 20]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- rnorm(4, mean=30, sd=18)
```

Comment: `Filter` is also nice if you want to do it all in one step - `Filter(function(x) x >= 20, rnorm(4, mean=30, sd=18))`